# Docusign Templates Api Parse Error Unexpected Token In Response

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, docusignapi

I'm getting a double callback and JSON.parse error when trying to make a [get call](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-node-client/blob/a993c515ea686744a0b35338834c81513e28667a/src/api/TemplatesApi.js#L1663) to the Docusign Api from the [Nodejs SDK](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/v2/reference/Templates/Templates/get/). The call is successful on the [api explorer](https://apiexplorer.docusign.com/#/esign-v2/restapi?categories=Templates&tags=Templates&operations=get) but no dice when calling from my MEAN stack.

The function is just a simple get call to validate a template id.

```
/**
* Validates Template Id with Docusign
*/
export async function validTemplateId(esignConfig: string, esignTemplateId: string):Promise<boolean> {

  const docusignAccount = await login(esignConfig);
  const { accountId } = docusignAccount;
  const templatesApi = await createApiClient(DocusignApiTypes.TemplatesApi, esignConfig);

  const templatesResult = await templatesApi.get(accountId, esignTemplateId);

  return templatesResult.envelopeTemplateDefinition.templateId === esignTemplateId;

}
```

The error seems to originate from superagent parsing the response. This the structure of error:

```
double callback!
double callback!
double callback!
 in JSON at position 15915ken 
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/youssef/Workspace/join_api/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/parsers/json.js:8:35)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:228:7)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:475:20)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1185:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21) {
  rawResponse: '{\r\n' +
    '  "envelopeTemplateDefinition": {\r\n' +
```

... The expected response does come through as the rawResponse ...

```
  '}',
  response: undefined,
  code: undefined,
  nw_error_message: 'Unexpected token \r in JSON at position 15915'
}
```

I've tried using Promises, await/async, .then+.catch no changes. I tried making an async get call that is available from the [typed version](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/docusign-esign) but the call drops and fails to load the response data.

[Failed to load response data on async get call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXuYF.png)

Comment: The links you provided suggest you're using the version 2.0 of the API. Do you mind trying the same on version 2.1 and see if you still experience the same?

Comment: Hey @InbarGazit thanks for the help! The stack and our account is unfortunately heavily dependant on version 2. The call works on the api explorer for version 2 so I would think it works for the sdk. I think it might something to do with the superagent dependency in the sdk right?

Comment: ok, we're unable to reproduce this issue. We will need more information about the problem, including how you do authentication and what is your login information .Perhaps opening a support case is the best way to proceed .

Comment: Ok thanks for the follow up, I'm not sure how to do that for the sandbox env I'm using, is there a link you can share that I can use to open a support case outside of CLM? This is a blocker at this point so I would love to expedite this issue

Comment: @InbarGazit Any help for this please?

Comment: please send an email to go-live@docusign.com with all your information and we will help you further.